# C# TCP client with backgroundWorker

Tags: c#, tcp, backgroundworker

I have a TCP client written in C#, and I use backgroundWorker to connect the server, something like this:

```
void ConnectToServer() {
    try {
        bwConnector = new BackgroundWorker();
        bwConnector.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bwConnector_DoWork);
        bwConnector.RunWorkerCompleted = new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(bwConnector_RunWorkerCompleted);
        bwConnector.RunWorkerAsync();
        e.Result = true;
    } catch {
        e.Result = false;
    }
}

void bwConnector_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) {

    clientSocket = new Socket(xxxxxx);
    clientSocket.Connect(xxxx);

    this.networkStream = new NetworkStream(this.clientSocket);
    this.bwReceiver = new BackgroundWorker();
    this.bwReceiver.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(StartReceive);
    ........
}
```

And I have a timer to check `clientSocket.Connected` is true or false, if false, I will call `ConnectToServer()` again for another connection attempt.

The problem is everytime I closed the application and reopen it, it seems that the last socket still remain there and have 2 sockets with the same IP but different ports connecting to the server.

Even I have something like this:

```
void bwConnector_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e) {

    ((BackgroundWorker)sender).Dipose();
    if (!((bool)e.Result)) {
        Debug.Log("failed");
    } else {
        Debug.Log("success");
    }
}
```

For disconnection, I have such codes:

```
System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkChange.NetworkAvailablilityChanged += new System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkAvailabilityChangedEventHandler(NetworkAvailabilityChanged);
private void NetworkChange_NetworkAvailabilityChanged(object sender , System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkAvailabilityEventArgs e)
    {
        if ( !e.IsAvailable )
        {
            this.OnNetworkDead(new EventArgs());
            this.OnDisconnectedFromServer(new EventArgs());
        }
        else
            this.OnNetworkAlived(new EventArgs());
    }
...............
public event DisconnectedEventHandler DisconnectedFromServer;
protected virtual void OnDisconnectedFromServer(EventArgs e)
{
    if ( DisconnectedFromServer != null )
    {
        DisconnectedFromServer(this , e);
    }
}
...........
void StartReceive(xxxxxxxxx) {
    while (this.clientSocket.Connected) {
        .........
    }
    this.Disconnect();
}

bool Disconnect() {
    if (this.clientSocket != null && this.clientSocket.Connected) {
        try {
            this.clientSocket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
            this.clientSocket.Close();
            return true;
        } catch {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: Where do you close the connection?

Comment: I added some codes to the question, thanks

Comment: If I understand correctly; you Open a connection-> ready the socket to accept data->Start receiving data->Close connection. This is all good and keeps everything in order. Problem seems to be arising from that Timer that immediately opens the connection as soon as it is closed. So just before your application is about exit, that Timer opens up a connection that is never closed.

Comment: Actually I dont have a "close connection" in normal situation since I dont expect the client to disconnect from the server actively. I only want the client to connect to the server again if the server is dead and reopen.

Comment: It is quite understandable, but you need to take care of the closing the connection one last time before exiting the application. Disable the Timer-> Check if connection open-> If open close it-> Exit gracefully

Comment: I dont have a "Exit gracefully" part in my application since I dont expect the client to close in normal usage. I just force quit my application and notice such problem. In this way, I'm afraid the same thing may occur if there is some problem with the network forcing the client to disconnect from the server.

Answer (score 1):

*Responding here as suggested by SO.*

Sadly, real world applications tend to fail and often time unexpected things happen. Being accidently closed by a user might be the most obvious "unexpected thing". I would have made sure that, if nothing else, at least everything is cleaned up on exit.

In the end, its all upto you.