# C# TcpListener Gets Stuck When Called For 2nd Time

Tags: c#, tcp

I have this code to connect to a panel.

```
    private void conn_init()
    {
        bwConnector = new BackgroundWorker(); 
        //the int "anarg" does nothing other than avoid a compiler error.
        //I do "anang=0" during Form_Load and I never use it, so you can ignore it.
        bwConnector.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler((sender, args) => conn_function(anarg));
        if (bwConnector.IsBusy != true)
        {
            bwConnector.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
    }
```

And the conn_function that my backgroundworker runs is:

```
    void conn_function(int a_param)
    {
        try
        {
            Int32 port = 7050;
            server = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, port);
            server.Start(); 

            Byte[] bytes = new Byte[256];
            String data = "";
            while (true)
            {
                data = "";
                int i;
                i = 1;
                client = server.AcceptTcpClient();
                stream = client.GetStream();
                while (i != 0)
                {
                    data = "";                        
                    try
                    {                               
                        i = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                        stream.Flush();
                    }
                    catch (SocketException e)
                    {
                        richTextBox1.Invoke(new EventHandler(delegate
                        {
                            richTextBox1.Text = e.Message;
                        }));
                    }

                    data = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes, 0, i);
                    //stuff that deals with the data
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I also have a timer that checks whether the connection is dead, and when it is dead, I run this code.

```
server.Stop();
conn_init();
```

My problem is, when I reset my device, my code can detect the disconnect and then it can reconnect, no issues. But when I reset it once more, I get the below error on this line:

```
//I get the error here and it says this:
//Unable to read data from the transport connection : An existing connection was 
//forcibly closed by the remote host
i = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
```

I am pretty sure I am missing something very simple, yet too technical for a beginner in connection coding like me. Because it works after the first reset, it just fails after the second. I thank you in advance for any assistance you might provide.

Comment: Where did you get the code?  You only accept a connection once unless you close the connection.  The accept should not be inside the loop.

Comment: This code is a slightly modified version of the below Stackexchange question.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16230127/c-sharp-tcp-client-with-backgroundworker

I do not recall where I got the loop part of the code but it was exactly like that, a nested while loop pair.

Comment: Microsoft removed their sample code recently that I recommend to OPs.  You cannot have two connections with the same 3 parameters 1) Source IP 2) Destination IP 3) Port number.  Probably the first connection never closed so the second never started.  You do not need to close connection.  You can keep sending/receiving many times on same connection.  I do not like closing connection but lots of people do close after each message.  To debug use from cmd.exe ">netstat -a" which gives status of connection.  You can add break point in code and see when connection opens and closes.

Comment: I got to the part where the code got stuck and I ran the cmd.exe command. Here is what I get, it is continuously spamming new TIME_WAIT s with new numbers at the end.
https://imgur.com/a/BzD12mG

Comment: Can I ask something else?
Is this possible to do using sockets? Maybe that could be a solution for me.

Comment: Time-Wait occurred because you closed the connection simultaneously at both client and server.  Only close a connection at client to prevent Time_Wait.  It is a bug in the TCP specification.   The TCPListener inherits the Socket class.  Most properties are not visible.  The missing socket properties with TCPListener is the property listener.Server.  The TCPClient the socket is client.Client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a number of issue with your code:

- You don't appear to be disposing the stream and client after it ends.
- `BackgroundWorker` is effectively deprecated, you should use `Task` and `await` instead. Use a `CancellationToken` to stop the server.
- Your server loop cannot handle multiple clients because it is not handing off the client to another thread/task.
- You don't need to call `GetStream` inside the loop.
- Do not swallow `catch (SocketException e)`, it usually leaves the socket in an unrecoverable state. Instead, display the message and shutdown the socket.

```cs
async Task RunServerLoop(int a_param, CancellationToken token)
{
    TcpListener server = null;
    try
    {
        Int32 port = 7050;
        server = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, port);
        server.Start(); 

        while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            client = await server.AcceptTcpClientAsync(token);
            Task.Run(() => HandleClient(client, token));
        }
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException)
    { //
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        if (server?.Active == true)
            server.Shutdown();
    }
}

async Task HandleClient(CancellationToken token)
{
    try
    {                               
        using client;
        using var stream = client.GetStream();
        Byte[] bytes = new Byte[256];
        int i;
        while ((i = await stream.ReadAsync(bytes, 0, bytes.Length, token)) > 0)
        {
            var data = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes, 0, i);
            //stuff that deals with the data
        }
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException)
    { //
    }
    catch (SocketException e)
    {
        richTextBox1.Invoke(new EventHandler(delegate
        {
            richTextBox1.Text = e.Message;
        }));
    }
}
```

You would call it like this:

```cs
CancellationTokenSource _cancel;

private async void conn_init()
{
    _cancel = new CancellationTokenSource();
    await RunServerLoop(somevalue, _cancel.Token);
}
```

I note that you don't appear to be using any kind of framing mechanism. Do not assume that a single `Send` from one side will necessarily be received in a single `Read` on the other. `Read` may or may not fill the buffer, and may or may not contain data from different messages from the other side.

Comment: I appreciate your answer, but now the IDE says "IsActive is not part of TcpListener". I will try to edit the code into a compilable state but any help would be very welcome, I am unable to continue reading the data of my panel after it is reset.

Comment: Sorry mistype, have fixed

Comment: Thank you very much, I resolved my issue. Can I ask something else?
I now receive partial data from my device, and I suspect the issue is with the encoding. I use this code:
data += Encoding.Default.GetString(bytes, 0, bytesRec);
to receive the below string:
"
 #A=A#F=A#T=A#L=19,19#C=17#V=2.77#P=.@@19.09.2022   14:40:16   00101006
&  MCP
.i&Fire.i#A=A#F=A#T=A#L=19,19#C=18#V=2.77#P=l&tesT buton.
"
But the "tesT buton" part at the end is always cut off. Do you have any idea about how I can receive the data in full? I tried UTF7-8-16-32, latin and others but no luck.

Comment: Like I said, you need to consider the beginning and end of each fram as TCp has no such concept, it's just a stream of bytes. `ReadAsync` will just return some bytes, you may need to piece it together from multiple calls to `ReadAsync`. See also https://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/04/message-framing.html